# Is there a connection error when using wifi to transfer files directly under uwp?

Tags: uwp

UWP application development environment:
1. Desktop
2.windows 10 Pro
3. vs2017 15.6
4. A plug-in wireless network card

When I use wifi direct technology to connect directly to the Android system, the connection is unstable
1.The "hs" encountered an error while applying power or reading the device configuration. This may be caused by a failure of your hardware or by poor connection. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070288)
2. No element found
The above two mistakes frequently appear. Ask experienced people to help us. Thank you. The code is as follows:

```js
 private async void ConnectionDevice()
        {
            try
            {
                if (directDevice != null)
                {
                    directDevice.Dispose();
                    directDevice = null;
                }
                await Views.MainPage.mainPage.Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
                {
                    _deviceViewModel.Message = "设备连接中...";
                });
                //

                WiFiDirectConnectionParameters connectionParameters = new WiFiDirectConnectionParameters();
                connectionParameters.PreferenceOrderedConfigurationMethods.Add(WiFiDirectConfigurationMethod.PushButton);
                //connectionParameters.PreferredPairingProcedure = WiFiDirectPairingProcedure.GroupOwnerNegotiation;


                directDevice = await WiFiDirectDevice.FromIdAsync(_deviceViewModel.DeviceId);
                directDevice.ConnectionStatusChanged += DirectDevice_ConnectionStatusChanged;
                if (directDevice != null)
                {
                    var EndpointPairs = directDevice.GetConnectionEndpointPairs();
                    //创建SOCKET连接监听
                    StreamSocketListener socketListener = new StreamSocketListener();
                    await socketListener.BindEndpointAsync(EndpointPairs[0].LocalHostName, "9568");
                    //连接监听事件
                    socketListener.ConnectionReceived += SocketListener_ConnectionReceived;
                    await Views.MainPage.mainPage.Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
                    {
                        _deviceViewModel.Message = "设备连成功";
                    });
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                await Views.MainPage.mainPage.Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
                {
                    _deviceViewModel.Message = ex.Message;
                });
                ConnectionDevice();
            }
        }
```

Comment: You need to do troubleshooting. If you connect to another Android phone, whether the connection is unstable. If you connect to the windows 10 device, whether the connection is unstable.

Comment: Thank you, I have a question I would like to ask.
I tested on two win10 devices. How do I respond to the connected device when it receives another device? Is it connected successfully?private void Listener_ConnectionRequested(WiFiDirectConnectionListener sender, WiFiDirectConnectionRequestedEventArgs args)
        {
            try
            {
                WiFiDirectConnectionRequest connectionRequest = args.GetConnectionRequest();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                tbox_Message.Text = ex.Message;
            }
        }

Comment: You could see the official code [sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/master/Samples/WiFiDirect/cs/Scenario2_Connector.xaml.cs#L237) use [DeviceInformationPairing.IsPaired Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Devices.Enumeration.DeviceInformationPairing.IsPaired) property, you could try it.

Answer (score 0):

i don't know if you solved it or not but i think this error from the Capabilities, make sure that you have this Capabilities:

```
<Capability Name="internetClient" />
 <Capability Name="internetClientServer" />
 <DeviceCapability Name="proximity" />
```